# Unable to read from file name in java which contains internationalized characters in its path

Tags: java, file, ascii

It works fine if the same file is selected with JFileChooser dialog

Path is something like
C:\テスト\sample.txt

The following code does not work

```
    String teststring = "C:\\テスト\\sample.txt";
    File file = new File(teststring);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    ...
```

It fails with FileNotFoundException

Comment: Which filesystem are you working with? If it works with JFileChooser then write a program and output the path read by the instance of JFileChooser and check if it is the same.

Comment: Not sure if that solves the issue but you need to escape the \ so the file name would be `teststring = "C:\\テスト\\sample.txt"`.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is most likely that when Java compiled, it was compiling in an encoding that did not match the file encoding for the テスト characters.  You can check that by inserting

```
 System.out.println(teststring);
```

which will probably not print テスト

Per default, the encoding is the platform encoding.  If your file is saved as UTF-8, you could compile with

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 YourClass.java
```

(or use the `encoding="UTF-8"` attribute for your `<javac>` task in [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

EDIT:

And as @assylias pointed out, backslashes need to be escaped!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the help.  The following change has resolved the problem apart from your solutions

```
...
File file = new File(new String(teststring.getBytes(),"utf8");
...
```